# cakephp 3 + can't update database record when using translate behavior and 'contain'

Tags: cakephp-3.0, behavior, translate, updating, contain

I am using CakePHP 3 and trying to do some pretty basic stuff.
I have two tables, articles and tags. 
Articles belongs to tags, and I made table tags translatable by attaching Translate behavior.

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table {        
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->addAssociations([
            'belongsTo' => ['Tags']
        ]);
    }         
}

class TagsTable extends Table {        
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->addAssociations([            
            'hasMany' => ['Articles'],            
        ]);
        $this->addBehavior('Translate', ['fields' => ['name']]);
    }       
}
```

In Article controller I have edit function:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public function edit($id = null) {
        $article = $this->Articles->get($id);
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {        
            $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'edit',$id]);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your article.'));
        }
        $this->request->data = $article;

        $tags = $this->Articles->Tags->find('list');
        $this->set('tags', $tags);
    }
}
```

In AppController I am setting locale language and at this point everything works fine, in edit.ctp file tags names are in local language and updating is working as it should.

**BUT**, when I replaced following line in edit function in ArticlesController:

```
$article = $this->Articles->get($id);
```

with line:

```
$article = $this->Articles->get($id, ['contain' =>  ['Tags']]);
```

I can no longer update article's tag.

If I change body and tag in my edit form, only new body is saved to my database. No error occurred, but tag_id is simply not changing.

If I remove translate behavior from the tags table, tags are not shown in local language, but can be updated again.

I am completely stuck, have no idea in which direction to search, why  I can not use translate behavior and 'contain' at the same time?

Any help is greatly appreciated.